# Use of can-find in dynamic query gives error

Tags: dynamic, query-string, progress-4gl, openedge

I need to find the customer records whose orderstatus is 'ordered'. How do I accomplish this using dynamic-query? Following code snippet raises an error:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE qry AS HANDLE.
CREATE QUERY qry.
qry:SET-BUFFERS(BUFFER customer:HANDLE, BUFFER order:HANDLE).
qry:QUERY-PREPARE("for each customer where customer.country eq 'USA' and 
                  can-find(order where order.custnum = customer.custnum 
                                   and order.orderstatus eq 'ordered')").
qry:QUERY-OPEN().

REPEAT :
  qry:GET-NEXT().
  IF qry:QUERY-OFF-END THEN LEAVE.
  DISP customer.custnum customer.name customer.salesrep.
END.
qry:QUERY-CLOSE().
DELETE OBJECT qry.
```

OR is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother with the `CAN-FIND` (you shouldn't anyway). Join the two tables instead.

Here's an example with some mockdata in temp-tables:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE customer NO-UNDO
    FIELD custnum AS INTEGER
    FIELD country AS CHARACTER
    FIELD NAME    AS CHARACTER
    FIELD salesrep AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE order NO-UNDO
    FIELD custnum AS INTEGER
    FIELD orderstatus AS CHARACTER.

CREATE customer.
ASSIGN customer.custnum  = 1
       customer.country  = "usa"
       customer.NAME     = "Name1"
       customer.salesrep = "jaan".

CREATE customer.
ASSIGN customer.custnum  = 2
       customer.country  = "usa"
       customer.NAME     = "Name2"
       customer.salesrep = "martin".

CREATE customer.
ASSIGN customer.custnum  = 3
       customer.country  = "sweden"
       customer.NAME     = "Name3"
       customer.salesrep = "john".

CREATE order.
ASSIGN order.custnum     = 1
       order.orderstatus = "cancelled".

CREATE order.
ASSIGN order.custnum     = 2
       order.orderstatus = "ordered".


CREATE order.
ASSIGN order.custnum      = 3
       order.orderstatus = "ordered".


DEFINE VARIABLE qry AS HANDLE.
CREATE QUERY qry.
qry:SET-BUFFERS(BUFFER customer:HANDLE, BUFFER order:HANDLE).
qry:QUERY-PREPARE("for each customer where customer.country eq 'USA', FIRST order where order.custnum = customer.custnum and order.orderstatus eq 'ordered'").
qry:QUERY-OPEN().

REPEAT :
  qry:GET-NEXT().
  IF qry:QUERY-OFF-END THEN LEAVE.
  DISP customer.custnum customer.name customer.salesrep.
END.
qry:QUERY-CLOSE().
DELETE OBJECT qry.
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. But i didn't understand one thing here,  how/why it doesn't retrieve all customer record whose country is USA.

Comment: Because of the query: it only returns those from usa with an order thats ordered.